# Change Payment Method Label for image

Tags: php, checkout, payment-methods

I'm trying to change the payment method label on my checkout page. I want to display an image for the particular method. My original code was:

```
<label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" style="text-transform:none">
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?> 
<?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
```

Here is what I am trying to do: The name of the method I want to change is "Laybuy"

```
<label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" style="text-transform:none">
<?php if($this->getMethodTitle($_method) = "Laybuy "): ?>
<img>goes here
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?> 
<?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it is not working at all. I am a complete php noob. How can I get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below.

Just go to phtml file of your payment method and you can try below code.

```
$img_url = $this->getSkinUrl('rwd/default/images/logo.png');

if ( $this->getMethodCode() == "your_payment_method_code" ) {
     <img width="100" src="<?php echo $img_url;?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Payment'); ?>" />
} else {
    // title here.
}
```

Comment: How would I get the payment method code? I have tried echo $this->getMethodCode($_method) for each method but it returns norhing??

Comment: Just echo $this->getMethodCode() this in phtml file of payment method and you can see your payment method code.